# div fade-in when window is scrolled a certain distance from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script in my `<head>` tag which animates my `div` when the window is 150px from the bottom. I am not sure how to alter it so it animates when a certain distance from the top.

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()-150){
  isShown = true;
  $('.footer-btn').fadeIn(500);
  }else{
  $('.footer-btn').fadeOut(500);
  }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `if($(window).scrollTop() == THE_EXPECT_VALUE)` should work.

Comment: `scroll` does not fire once for every single pixel, so if you rely on an exact match (using `==`) you might miss it.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. The question is in the second sentence of my post. I want it to animate in from the top after 150px not 150px before the bottom. This function works perfectly, just works from the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jQuery script that I use in a site to set the animation from the top.

Change the value of `offset()` to control the fade-in activation position.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // browser window scroll position (in pixels) where button will appear
  // adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
  var offset = 200,

    // duration of the animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,

    // bind with the button link
    $animation = $('.animation');

  // display or hide the button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) ? $animation.addClass('visible'):
      $animation.removeClass('visible');
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 800px;
}
#button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
.animation {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible;  /* the button becomes visible */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p>SCROLL DOWN</p>
  <a id="button" class="animation">BUTTON</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmz6g8kh/4/