# Showing a div only when a certain div's height is > than set height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tabbing module I created that has scrollable content areas. I made a quick blinking arrow style to let the users know that this box is scrollable. I would like to make it so this div is only visible if my content (scrollable text box area) is above a certain height.

For example, my scrollable area is always set to `height:450px`. So I need a way to figure out how to get the height of the content area, then if is less than 450px height, to not show my div `more-info`.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hkpzagz/1/) with a working demo.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="tabs-left app-about-page">
      <div class="more-info"></div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">Donor Acquisition</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">Donor Cultivation</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones">Donor Retention</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">Donor Blogging</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">Donor Engagement</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
          </div>


          <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
          </div>


          <div class="tab-pane" id="c">
            </div>

          <div class="tab-pane" id="d">
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane" id="e">
          </div>

        </div><!-- /tab-content -->
      </div><!-- /tabbable -->
```

From some searching and piecing together, I found something like this, so assume this is the starting point.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".tab-pane").height() > 450 {
        jQuery(".more-info").fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        jQuery(".more-info").hide(100);
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking to use the jQuery `offset()` method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31591158/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B hmm, this seems like it would only be helpful if I needed it to show while scrolling, I would prefer for it to be static from load showing whether or not the content area is scrollable.

Comment: Only show blinking arrow when content exceeds 450px height. Arrow always in same position, fixed at bottom. Correct?

Comment: @Michael_B yes, that is correct.

Comment: Are the number of tabs in your module fixed? Is the content static? In other words, will tabs and content change dynamically, or could you just apply the arrow to your scrollable content using a CSS `.class`?

Comment: The tabs will be static, but the content will be getting changed out every so often. I was going to use this as a last ditch effort if I couldn't find an answer to do it a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make use of the `shown.bs.tab` event, to show and hide your arrow div.

[**Togglable tabs Events**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)

> **shown.bs.tab**
>
> This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

```js
$('.more-info').css('display', 'none');
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var activeContentElem = $($(e.target).attr('href'));
  if (activeContentElem[0].scrollHeight > activeContentElem.height()) {
    $('.more-info').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('.more-info').css('display', 'none'); 
  }

})
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 106px;
  height: 106.5px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F2F2F0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-bottom: #FFF 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.nav-tabs li:last-child{
  border:none;
}

.nav-tabs li a{
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 31px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #DBDBDA;
  cursor:pointer;

}

.nav-tabs > li.active, .nav-tabs > li.active a,  .nav-tabs > li a:active, .nav-tabs > li.active > li:focus, .nav-tabs >li a:focus {
  background:rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.45);
  color:#FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-content {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.tab-content .tab-pane {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tab-pane p{
  margin: 0  0 16px 0;
}

.tab-pane p:first-child{
  margin:5px 0 16px;
}

.tab-pane h1{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDA;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.tab-pane img{
  max-width: 70%;
}


.tab-content .active {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 450px !important;
  padding: 0px 15px 0 0px;
}

.list-group {
  width: 100%;
}
.list-group .list-group-item {
  height: 50px;
}
.list-group .list-group-item h4, .list-group .list-group-item span {
  line-height: 11px;
}




@-webkit-keyframes circleBounce {
  0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9); opacity: 0;}
  20% {opacity: 0.5;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
  80% {opacity: 0.5;}
  100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1); opacity:0;}
}

.more-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(51, 181, 229);
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.more-info:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 17px);
  left: calc(50% - 17px);
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border: 1px solid rgb(51, 181, 229);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: circleBounce 2.5s linear infinite;
}

.more-info:hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(51, 181, 229, .15);
  cursor:inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-left app-about-page">
  <div class="more-info"></div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">Donor Acquisition</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">Donor Cultivation</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones">Donor Retention</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">Donor Blogging</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">Donor Engagement</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="a">
      <h1>Donor Acquisition</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="tab-pane" id="b">
      <h1>Donor Cultivation</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
    </div>


    <div class="tab-pane" id="c">
      <h1>Donor Retention</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="d">
      <h1>Nonprofit Blogging</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="e">
      <h1>Nonprofit Engagement</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet. Phasellus id est lacus. Pellentesque a elementum velit, a tempor nulla. Mauris mauris lectus, tincidunt et purus rhoncus, eleifend convallis turpis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce convallis consectetur ligula. Morbi dapibus tellus a ipsum sollicitudin aliquet.</p>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /tab-content -->
</div><!-- /tabbable -->
```

Comment: Edit: Never mind, figured out how to call it. Realized it was only being called on toggle. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So little seconds appart of your answer, the essence being the same, but yours have expanded information. Upvote

Comment: No problem, i was just about to post that. You were faster.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First, start your `.more-info` class as hidden in css.
Then, you could check the height of the content of your tab every time the visible tab changes, and if it is greater than 450px, swap visibility of your more info button.

This is the jQuery snippet:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var div = $($(e.target).attr('href'));

    $('.more-info').hide();
    if (div.get(0).scrollHeight > 450)
        $('.more-info').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here, but I looked around some more and came up with this.

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

and some combination of this..

```
[DIV].style.visibility='visible'

[DIV].style.visibility='hidden'
```

then use an if statement?

Kind of new to coding, but maybe this is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind an event to your menu anchors that checks the height of your active div against the scroll height of that div and show or hides the blinking arrow.

Using JQuery, something like this so that it triggers after your bootstrap finishes:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (){
    ToggleMoreInfoArrow();
     //Call the toggle every time the content changes.
    });

ToggleMoreInfoArrow(); //Call it the first time the page loads.
});

function ToggleMoreInfoArrow()
{
        if( $('div.active').prop('scrollHeight') < $('div.active').height())
        {
            $('.more-info').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.more-info').show();
        }
}
```

Edit: I'm not sure how your "active" class gets set, but you'd want to run the height check code after that happens. This could be on page load or wherever, the `if` statement is the important bit.

Edit: See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hkpzagz/7/

Comment: It's done using bootstrap, active is being set within my bootstrap.min.js, so I'm not sure I'll be able to fire this function before hand.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can bind the event to 'shown.bs.tab' I'll edit with a code update. Please see the working fiddle above! :).

Answer (score 0):

Hello multinumbered user, I didn't like the script there was in example, and I changed the CSS a bit, moving "more" button to the right bottom corner, but I did the following:
1. you should always have .tab-pane to be of the set height on start and not scrolled, so I changed the CSS to be "overflow: hidden"

2. I wrote a function that checks the height of tab content and either activate or desactivate "more"
3. If "more" button is clicked, the tab content CSS 'overflow-y' option is changed to 'auto' - this adds vertical scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/9hkpzagz/8/

here is my js code:

```
function checkHeightAndSetMore(clickedMore){
    var activeTabH=$('.tab-content .active').height();
    if(activeTabH >450){
      $('div.more-info').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
    $('div.more-info').fadeOut();
    }
    if(clickedMore == 1){
        $('.tab-content .active').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        $('div.more-info').fadeOut();
    }

}
$(document).ready(function(){
checkHeightAndSetMore(0);
    $('.more-info').click(function(){        
       checkHeightAndSetMore(1);
    });
});
```